# Having trouble with rc.local scripting

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

Hello there Stack Exchange,

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi to make a sort of Kiosk display unit out of a TV screen. I figured that this would be a simple enough process, write a startup script that actives LXDE, x11vnc and chromium to the page I want and it's done. But unfortunately, I can't seem to get my rc.local script to work exactly as I want it too and I'm not sure why. This is the code I have added to rc.local

```
su pi -c startx&
su pi -c x11vnc -display :0 -q -usepw -rfbport 5901
su pi -c chromium --kiosk --incognito "http://www.springwater.ca/"
```

When the machine is booting it will run the startx command but not the x11vnc or chromium commands. Have I missed something here? Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Thanks,

```
Michael
```

Comment: and you're sure that `x11vnc` exists? If yes, then it must be a PATH problem. Either add line like `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/x11Stuff"` OR just hard-code the full path to each call in your script, i.e. `su pi -c /path/to/x11stuff/x11vnc ....`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still having trouble with it. I located the full path to x11vnc with the which command and added it to the call in my script, but it is still not initializing. I also added a 20 second sleep after my startx call to make sure that the commands weren't colliding. It's still not working though. Any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think @thatotherguy has a good point. A good `start` process should return to the cmd-line (so-to-speak) once it has done everything it needs to and running it in the background with '&' defeats its purpose, and will only make the other cmds fail (as he says!). If it "hangs" and never returns, then, that's a different story, did you find documentation that said OK to use '&' to background the start process? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use "nodm" (as package in Debian or from here: http://www.enricozini.org/sw/nodm/) on my Raspberry to login my user and start LXDE. Then autostart all needed applications as  described here: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart.

Edit to answer the comment:
In Debian you can configure the user (and other things) in the file /etc/default/nodm. 
I have set the parameter:

```
    # User to autologin for
    NODM_USER=dashboard
```

best wishes,
Matthias

Comment: I'm quite interested in this method actually. Do you use nodm to start your 'pi' user or do you run it in root? I'm having a hard time figuring out how to force nodm to run a specific user, all I can get it to boot into is root.

Answer (score 3):

It will take several seconds before the X server loads and is able to accept connections, but with your &, x11vnc and chromium will try and fail immediately.

After the startx line, you could add a simple `sleep 30` to give it time to start, or maybe even poll it:

```
until xwininfo -root -display :0; do sleep 1; done
```